# Show Loading Indicator for a timer based observable rendered using async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I have an angular http request which I have made auto refresh using rxjs timer...

```
this.data$ = timer(0, 1000 * 10).pipe(
  flatMap(() => this.service.getData())
);
```

I am showing this observable in my template using async pipe within an if else to show a loading indicator before it completes...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else loading">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

This works great. But when the timer triggers every 10 seconds I would like the loading template to show again until the http request completes. I would guess I need a way to form this rxjs expression so that every 10 seconds it immediately emits a null or something then executes the request and then emits the request response object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind discarding the previously loaded result while it's loading you can emit `null` before triggering the request:

```
this.data$ = timer(0, 1000 * 10).pipe(
  flatMap(() => concat(of(null), this.service.getData())),
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!